# How do I select/query a string (# of characters varies) before a delimiter in Postgres SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to SQL. I've been practicing a lot recently.
I've stumbled into this problem (***please see imgur link***)

How do I do the ff:

1. Select/query the each degrees before a delimiter and show it in a new--***column degrees*** (***as shown in the table***)
2. For those without a degree, like example ***Mansoon Ahmed***, reflect in ***column degrees*** as blank

Link to the Table--> https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBKYw.jpg

Thanks for all the help! Have a great day ahead!

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split_part()` to get the part before the string:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN strpos(col, ',') <> 0
            THEN trim(split_part(col, ',', 1))
       END AS degree
FROM tab;
```

Note that this relies on the fact that a `CASE` expression returns NULL if none of the conditions are met and there is no `ELSE` branch.

Comment: HOLY!!! You're a God, Sir! It worked. Thank you! I'll study and analyze this code. :D